# JavaScript calculator displays NaN

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

Trying to make a simple javascript calculator and having a problem, when pushing a button and activate function console reflect NaN. Cannot figure out whats a problem.Function somehow working is not right. Code is in snippet.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var screen = document.getElementById("screen");
  var keys = document.getElementsByClassName("keys");
  var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

  (function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {
      span[i].onclick = theCode;
    }

    function theCode() {

      var operators = ['+', '-', '/', '*'];
      var btnVal = this.innerHTML;
      var srnVal = screen.innerHTML;


      var opers = {
        '*': function(num) {
          return (num[0] * num[1])
        },
        '+': function(num) {
          return (num[0] + num[1])
        },
        '-': function(num) {
          return (num[0] - num[1])
        },
        '/': function(num) {
          return (num[0] / num[1])
        }
      }

      var detectOp = function(value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < operators.length; i++) {
          if (operators[i] == value) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      };

      function iteration(num) {
        num = num + '';
        for (var i = num.indexOf - 1; i > srnVal.length; i--) {
          num = srnVal[i] + num;
          return num;
        }

        for (var j = num.indexOf + 1; j < srnVal.length; j++) {
          num = num + srnVal[j];
          return num;
        }

        return parseInt(num);
      }

      if (btnVal == '=') {
        for (var i = 0; i < srnVal.length; i++) {
          if (detectOp(srnVal[i])) {
            screen.innerHTML = opers[srnVal[i]](iteration);
          }
        }

      } else {
        srnVal += btnVal;
        screen.innerHTML += btnVal;
      }
    }
  })();

};
```

```css
/* Basic reset */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Better text styling */
  font: bold 14px Arial, sans-serif;
}
/* Finally adding some IE9 fallbacks for gradients to finish things up */

/* A nice BG gradient */

html {
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #fff 20%, #ccc);
  background-size: cover;
}
/* Using box shadows to create 3D effects */

#calculator {
  width: 325px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 20px 20px 9px;
  background: #9dd2ea;
  background: linear-gradient(#9dd2ea, #8bceec);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #009de4, 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* Top portion */

.top span.clear {
  float: left;
}
/* Inset shadow on the screen to create indent */

.top #screen {
  height: 40px;
  width: 212px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* Typography */
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: right;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
/* Clear floats */

.keys,
.top {
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* Applying same to the keys */

.keys span,
.top span.clear {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 66px;
  height: 36px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0 7px 11px 0;
  color: #888;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  /* prevent selection of text inside keys */
  user-select: none;
  /* Smoothing out hover and active states using css3 transitions */
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
/* Remove right margins from operator keys */

/* style different type of keys (operators/evaluate/clear) differently */

.keys span.operator {
  background: #FFF0F5;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.keys span.eval {
  background: #f1ff92;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #9da853;
  color: #888e5f;
}
.top span.clear {
  background: #ff9fa8;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #ff7c87;
  color: white;
}
/* Some hover effects */

.keys span:hover {
  background: #9c89f6;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #6b54d3;
  color: white;
}
.keys span.eval:hover {
  background: #abb850;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #717a33;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.top span.clear:hover {
  background: #f68991;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #d3545d;
  color: white;
}
/* Simulating "pressed" effect on active state of the keys by removing the box-shadow and moving the keys down a bit */

.keys span:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px #6b54d3;
  top: 4px;
}
.keys span.eval:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px #717a33;
  top: 4px;
}
.top span.clear:active {
  top: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px #d3545d;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="calculator">
      <!-- Screen and clear key -->
      <div class="top">
        <span class="clear">C</span>
        <div id="screen"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="keys">
        <!-- operators and other keys -->
        <span value="7">7</span>
        <span value="8">8</span>
        <span value="9">9</span>
        <span class="operator" value="+">+</span>
        <span value="4">4</span>
        <span value="5">5</span>
        <span value="6">6</span>
        <span class="operator" value="-">-</span>
        <span value="1">1</span>
        <span value="2">2</span>
        <span value="3">3</span>
        <span class="operator" value="/">/</span>
        <span value="0">0</span>
        <span>.</span>
        <span class="eval" value="=">=</span>
        <span class="operator" value="*">*</span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: Euhm where is the code? if you don't provide code we cannot help you.

Comment: Please provide your code ?

Comment: Set breakpoint or use `debugger` command in your script so you can step through each line of the execution and see what all the variable values are at each step. Will be valuable learning experience

Comment: Did it before, cant understand why code isnot executing. I think that problem is, that code reads operands, not numbers in the array. So I thought that somebody can help me to fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without more detail - but NaN (not a number) may imply that your calculator is trying to perform numerical operations on a non number.

To resolve, you can wrap number variables in parseFloat(), i.e.

```
var number = document.getElementById("inputBox1").value;
```

becomes

```
var number = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inputBox1").value);
```

Edit:

Based on the code you provided, I think applying my fix to some of the innerHTML pulls your doing should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the line

```
screen.innerHTML = opers[srnVal[i]](iteration);
```

You're properly fetching your operation function with `opers[srnVal[i]]` but then you invoke it while giving it a function as argument when it's expecting an array or 2 numbers. You end up attempting a numerical operation with `undefined`, which gives you `NaN`.

This is the part you need to fix.

**Edit:** I'm really not sure what your `iteration` function is supposed to be doing, but it looks to me like it's some failing javascript that would generate errors if it came to be executed anyway. What you need to do here is to parse your expression and evaluate the result. I've written a working example, here is the piece of code that makes the evaluation work:

```
if (btnVal == '=') {
    var expression = srnVal.split(''),
            cursor,
            leftHand,
            operation;

    while (expression.length) {
        cursor = expression.shift();
        if (detectOp(cursor)) {
            operation = opers[cursor];
        } else if (operation && leftHand) {
            leftHand = operation([leftHand, parseInt(cursor)]);
            operation = null;
        } else if(leftHand) {
            leftHand = parseInt(leftHand + cursor);
        } else {
            leftHand = parseInt(cursor);
        }
    }
    screen.innerHTML = leftHand;
} else {
    srnVal += btnVal;
    screen.innerHTML += btnVal;
}
```

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var screen = document.getElementById("screen");
  var keys = document.getElementsByClassName("keys");
  var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

  (function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {
      span[i].onclick = theCode;
    }

    function theCode() {

      var operators = ['+', '-', '/', '*'];
      var btnVal = this.innerHTML;
      var srnVal = screen.innerHTML;


      var opers = {
        '*': function(num) {
          return (num[0] * num[1])
        },
        '+': function(num) {
          return (num[0] + num[1])
        },
        '-': function(num) {
          return (num[0] - num[1])
        },
        '/': function(num) {
          return (num[0] / num[1])
        }
      }

      var detectOp = function(value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < operators.length; i++) {
          if (operators[i] == value) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      };

      if (btnVal == '=') {
        var expression = srnVal.split(''),
          cursor,
          leftHand,
          operation;

        while (expression.length) {
          cursor = expression.shift();
          if (detectOp(cursor)) {
            operation = opers[cursor];
          } else if (operation && leftHand) {
            leftHand = operation([leftHand, parseInt(cursor)]);
            operation = null;
          } else if (leftHand) {
            leftHand = parseInt(leftHand + cursor);
          } else {
            leftHand = parseInt(cursor);
          }
        }
        screen.innerHTML = leftHand;
      } else {
        srnVal += btnVal;
        screen.innerHTML += btnVal;
      }
    }
  })();

};
```

```css
/* Basic reset */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Better text styling */
  font: bold 14px Arial, sans-serif;
}
/* Finally adding some IE9 fallbacks for gradients to finish things up */

/* A nice BG gradient */

html {
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #fff 20%, #ccc);
  background-size: cover;
}
/* Using box shadows to create 3D effects */

#calculator {
  width: 325px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 20px 20px 9px;
  background: #9dd2ea;
  background: linear-gradient(#9dd2ea, #8bceec);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #009de4, 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* Top portion */

.top span.clear {
  float: left;
}
/* Inset shadow on the screen to create indent */

.top #screen {
  height: 40px;
  width: 212px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* Typography */
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: right;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
/* Clear floats */

.keys,
.top {
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* Applying same to the keys */

.keys span,
.top span.clear {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 66px;
  height: 36px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0 7px 11px 0;
  color: #888;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  /* prevent selection of text inside keys */
  user-select: none;
  /* Smoothing out hover and active states using css3 transitions */
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
/* Remove right margins from operator keys */

/* style different type of keys (operators/evaluate/clear) differently */

.keys span.operator {
  background: #FFF0F5;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.keys span.eval {
  background: #f1ff92;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #9da853;
  color: #888e5f;
}
.top span.clear {
  background: #ff9fa8;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #ff7c87;
  color: white;
}
/* Some hover effects */

.keys span:hover {
  background: #9c89f6;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #6b54d3;
  color: white;
}
.keys span.eval:hover {
  background: #abb850;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #717a33;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.top span.clear:hover {
  background: #f68991;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #d3545d;
  color: white;
}
/* Simulating "pressed" effect on active state of the keys by removing the box-shadow and moving the keys down a bit */

.keys span:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px #6b54d3;
  top: 4px;
}
.keys span.eval:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px #717a33;
  top: 4px;
}
.top span.clear:active {
  top: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px #d3545d;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="calculator">
      <!-- Screen and clear key -->
      <div class="top">
        <span class="clear">C</span>
        <div id="screen"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="keys">
        <!-- operators and other keys -->
        <span value="7">7</span>
        <span value="8">8</span>
        <span value="9">9</span>
        <span class="operator" value="+">+</span>
        <span value="4">4</span>
        <span value="5">5</span>
        <span value="6">6</span>
        <span class="operator" value="-">-</span>
        <span value="1">1</span>
        <span value="2">2</span>
        <span value="3">3</span>
        <span class="operator" value="/">/</span>
        <span value="0">0</span>
        <span>.</span>
        <span class="eval" value="=">=</span>
        <span class="operator" value="*">*</span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
```

**PS:** it should be noted that this piece of code works with several operands, but will **NOT** take operations precedance into account.

Comment: Set the function iteration with (num) var num = []; i think it should help but it didnt. Im not sure that I know how to realize it in another way.

Comment: @VladyslavNaidonov I've added a snippet and a focus on the piece of code that replaces the part that's failing. Mind that while it is a working example, it is incomplete and will **NOT** respect operations precedance. You'll have to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Can work if you change:

```
screen.innerHTML = opers[srnVal[i]](iteration);
```

by

```
screen.innerHTML = eval(srnVal);
```

Comment: Should make it wothout eval

Answer (score 0):

When asking JavaScript questions, it is a good idea to use one of the online JavaScript develop/test tools to create the scenario that you are having a problem with. This makes it much easier for others to debug your code. I typically use JSFiddle, but there are others (e.g., CodePen and Plnkr). Here is a JSFiddle of your original code: https://jsfiddle.net/xpodpd1z/.

Regarding your issue, there are several logical errors in your code. In particular, the `iteration` function and the code that handles the `=` operation.

First off, the `=` operation code:

```
if (btnVal == '=') {
    for (var i = 0; i < srnVal.length; i++) {
        if (detectOp(srnVal[i])) {
            screen.innerHTML = opers[srnVal[i]](iteration);
        }
    }
}
```

You are iterating through the characters in your input (`srnVal`). When you find an operator character, you are acting on it and assigning the result to the output (`screen.innerHTML`). This approach may or may not be adequate when there are multiple operators in the input, depending on how you want to handle operator precedence. Regardless, it will not do anything right now because of the way `iteration` is used.

Your `opers` variable is a hash of functions that expect an array of two numbers as input. You are referencing and calling the `opers` function correctly, but you are passing in a reference to a function and not an array of two numbers.

I think your intent here was for the `iteration` function to return the two numbers, but you are not actually calling the function (the `()` to call the function is missing), and this may not work if there are multiple operators in the input.

If you ignore the multiple-operators scenario for now and just concentrate on number-operator-number, your logic needs to do the following:

- Parse out the first number and convert it from a string to a number
- Parse out the operator and get the function for it
- Parse out the second number and convert it from a string to a number
- Execute the operator on the two numbers and assign the result to the output

Now for the `iteration` function. I think that it was intended to parse the numbers from the input, but it is really difficult to be sure because of the logical issues in it.

The first piece of code in that function looks like this:

```
num = num + '';
for (var i = num.indexOf - 1; i > srnVal.length; i--) {
    num = srnVal[i] + num;
    return num;
}
```

You are converting `num` to a string, then entering a loop. There are several issues in the loop code. First off, `num.indexOf` is a function and you are not calling it (the `()` are missing again). Second, your loop condition is `i > srnVal.length` and then on the next line you are accessing `srnVal[i]`. This will cause an out-of-bounds error.

I'm reluctant to just fix it for you since appear to be learning JavaScript. I think you need to start by doing some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) on your `iteration` function to decide exactly what it is you intend it to do.

Comment: What would you say could be the best way to take operations precedance into account ?

Comment: If you're writing a calculator, look into Reverse Polish Notation. Parsing the input into that format is a great way to handle precedence.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the first for loop where you forgot to add parentheses.

`span[i].onclick = theCode;` should be `span[i].onclick = theCode();`

Answer (score -1):

You are probably getting strings instead of numbers when you run the calculation. Use `parseInt()` to type juggle. I would also recommend use `console.log()` to figure out exactly what is getting passed into the calculation function. Once you know that, I imagine that solve this problem will be relatively easy.